# Everytime i clicked on .approvers > a I can't get the tr id name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<tr class="job-order__row" id="accounting" style="display:none;">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Accounting Personnel</td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions pull-right approvers">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i></a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="job-order__row" id="hr" style="display:none;">
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>Luke</td>
  <td>HR Personnel</td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions pull-right approvers">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i></a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="job-order__row" id="crm" style="display:none;">
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>CRM Personnel</td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions pull-right approvers">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i></a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and the javascript/jquery code

```
$(document).on('click', '.approvers > a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $id = $('.approvers > a').parents('tr').attr('id');
    $('#'+$id).hide();
  });
```

The problem is, when i try to click on any of `.approvers > a` this part here
`$('.approvers > a').parents('tr').attr('id');` of the code only return the Id name `"crm"`.

What I want to do is everytime i clicked on `.approvers > a` I will get the `tr` id name.

Anyone has the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: Use `$(this)` inside event handler. It refers to the element on which event has occurred. `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');`

Comment: you wants to get tr/row id when you click?

Comment: @SandipPatel yes, i want to get the id name

Comment: click event will fire on first anchor/a of .approvers click or any document element click?

Comment: it will fire in any under the tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Tushar said is use `$(this)` for refer to the element clicked and `closest()` for get the first parent element.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.approvers > a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert($id)
    $('#'+$id).hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="job-order__row" id="accounting" style="">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Accounting Personnel</td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions pull-right approvers">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i>click</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="job-order__row" id="hr" style="">
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>Luke</td>
  <td>HR Personnel</td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions pull-right approvers">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i>click</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="job-order__row" id="crm" style="">
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>CRM Personnel</td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions pull-right approvers">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i>click</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will give you **clicked item tr/row id**.

```
$("table tr").on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
});
```